# ftp: in remote machine, file owner changes with the change in username used for logging in the remote machine

Tags: permissions, ftp, pure-ftpd

It was a wonder for me to see why the file owner changes when I log in the remote machine with different usernames.

Please see: 1st I logged in a remote machine using username : peacenews. 
I entered a directory (`pwd` outputs `/` as the directory)

When I run `ls` to see the files there, I get the below:
(I am only showing the last few lines of the output)

```
-rwx rwxrwx    1 peacenew 504      198311940 Oct  4 02:21 Rotary club ORC, Delhi .m2p 
drwxrwxrwx    2 peacenew 504          4096 Sep 19 23:09 Vizianagaram, AP 
-rwxrwxrwx    1 peacenew 504      296817474 Oct  3 10:30 dehradun-prem.VOB 
226-Options: -l 
226 18 matches total
```

Then I logged out and reconnected as anonymous user. This time also I logged in the same directory (having the same filenames)
See the output of ls please (last few lines only):

```
-rwxrwxrwx    1 504      504      198311940 Oct  4 02:21 Rotary club ORC, Delhi .m2p 
drwxrwxrwx    2 504      504          4096 Sep 19 23:09 Vizianagaram, AP 
-rwxrwxrwx    1 504      504      296817474 Oct  3 10:30 dehradun-prem.VOB 
226-Options: -l 
226 18 matches total
```

Have a note at the 3rd column and compare with the previous one. Group owner for the files are the same but file owner changes. How come? It's a wonder!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the matter on my own. I did my research by doing ftp to my own server.
The thing is that the file owner isn't changing. The 1st output shows the username and the 2nd shows the user ID for the same user. So simple but for confirming this I had to experiment with my own server.